# css precedence with same levels

Tags: html, css

Consider the following example https://jsfiddle.net/wdvpubau/4/.

In this example both `display:block` and `float:left` are of same specificity which is 2.Still why , `display:block` is overriden and float:left takes precedence.

Ideally `display:block` should have displayed 4 divs one below the other

Comment: there is no precedence taking place when dealing with different properties. You are misunderstanding the whole concept. Finally `display` and `float` control different functionalities.

Comment: Please don't circumvent the quality filter. Either include the code from the fiddle within the question, or don't link to a fiddle at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` and `float` don't interact the way you think. Elements that have `display: block` can still float next to each other if their width allows it.

In other words, `float` has precedence over `display` when it comes to placing elements.

Comment: Correct, this has nothing to do with specificity at all. @user1907849: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo